# PHP truncate commas in string

Tags: php, string

in PHP, I want to change this string:

`",,,3,4,,,5,6,,7,8,"`

into this:

`"3,4,5,6,7,8"`

I've managed to strip commas at the beginning and end of the string, but this only accomplish 50% of my need:

```
<?php
$hello = ",,,3,4,5,6,,7,8,";
echo rtrim(ltrim($hello,","),",");
```

result:

`"3,4,,,5,6,,7,8"`

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use trim() and Regx to achieve this, please have a look on the below code, it may help you

```
$from = ",,,,,,3,4,,,5,6,,7,8,,,";
echo $from;
echo "<pre>";
$to = preg_replace('/,+/', ',', trim($from,","));
echo $to;
```

Comment: I like this solution because it just call 2 functions which is non-array functions :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Do this little trick:

```
$hello = ",,,3,4,,,5,6,,7,8,";
$hello = implode(",",array_filter(explode(',',$hello)));
```

If your string is more complicated (i.e. it's a CSV which may potentially have fields wrapped in " " to escape commas you can do this:

```
$hello = ",,,3,4,,,5,6,,\"I,have,commas\",,7,8,";
$fields = array_filter(str_getcsv($hello));
$hello = str_putcsv($fields);
```

Where `str_putcsv` is defined in https://gist.github.com/johanmeiring/2894568 as

```
if (!function_exists('str_putcsv')) {
    function str_putcsv($input, $delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"') {
        $fp = fopen('php://temp', 'r+b');
        fputcsv($fp, $input, $delimiter, $enclosure);
        rewind($fp);
        $data = rtrim(stream_get_contents($fp), "\n");
        fclose($fp);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`implode(",", array_filter(explode(",", ",,,3,4,,,5,6,,7,8,"))`

That's a little bit to read, but essentially `explode` the string on a comma, call `array_filter` on the result of that, then `implode` it back together.

Comment: Thank you for your response. :)